# EntityStore vs. ResourceData

Tags: entity, resourceobject

I find that I have a local file, "General-Topology-EntityStore.wl" (and I don't recall exactly how I got it!).

Evaluating

```
Import["General-Topology-EntityStore.wl"]
```

gives as result an `EntityStore` object:

[image: General-Topology EntityStore]

On the other hand, going to the Wolfram Data Repository for this data and doing as instructed, that is, evaluating

```
ResourceObject["General Topology EntityStore"]
```

returns:

[image: General Topology EntityStore]

**Questions:**

1. Exactly what is the difference between these two objects?
2. How can one convert each one into the other?
3. How does one begin to use the data in each?

Comment: The latter is basically a reference to the data in the first with some extra metadata. You can convert it to the first using `ResourceData` on it but you can’t go the other direction unless you know all the metadata. You can use the data by appending it to `$EntityStores` and using the `Entity*` functions to look things up about it.

Comment: @b3m2a1: As of version 11.3, `$EntityStores` is superceded by `EntityRegister`, `EntityStores`, and `EntityUnregister`. I *think* the way to begin is with `EntityRegister[
 ResourceData[ResourceObject["General Topology EntityStore"]]]`.  But I still need help with accessing and using the data: I find the documentation too scattered among scores of functions and without a tutorial. Can you point to such a tutorial that uses an existing entity store?

Comment: Once you register your custom entity type, you can simply use it as if it were a built in one. e.g. `EntityList["GeneralTopologyConcept"]`, `EntityProperties["GeneralTopologyConcept"]`, `EntityValue[
 Entity["GeneralTopologyConcept", "DiscreteTopology"], "SummaryGrid"]`. The ref page for `Entity` and `EntityValue` should be good starting points.

Comment: It would be good to have an answer combining the information in these comments! Given my limited knowledge here, I ought not be the one to synthesize such an answer from the comments!

Comment: @ChipHurst: Nope, what you say does not seem to work. I evaluated `obj = ResourceObject["General Topology EntityStore"]`, then `store = ResourceData[obj]`, and clicked on the button on the output from the latter to store this in the notebook. But then input `EntityList["GeneralTopologyConcept"]` gives output `Missing["UnknownType", "GeneralTopologyConcept"]`.

Comment: You need to use `EntityRegister[store]` first.

Comment: @ChipHurst: OK, this puts it all together -- which is what seems to be missing from the docs: `obj = ResourceObject["itsName"]`, next `store=ResourceData[obj]`, next `EntityRegister[store]`. And then querying the data can be carried out.

Comment: "reference to the data in the first with some extra metadata." why can't the metadata be stored or referenced from the EntityStore directly?